# Ruby on Rails: application wide filtering with id in every model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing this software for clubs where people can just sign in and add scores, players, teams etc. Now I of course have many clubs and for every model there is club_id column to identify that club. Is there some easier way to check for current club than writing something like this:

`News.where("club_id = ?", @club_id)`

I found it too hard to abstract this proplem so much that I could find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make some basic class for your models:

```
class ClubStuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true # <--- don't forget
  default_scope { where(club_id: Thread.current[:club_id]) }
end
```

and make your models out of it:

```
class News < ClubStuff
```

Then:

```
# in ApplicationController
before_filter { Thread.current[:club_id] = params[:club_id] }
```

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what kind of solution I was hoping to find out! I thought about scopes (still I would've had to write it every time for query) but didn't realize there was this default_scope functionality. Rails is just great! Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why create an extra id (club_id) when there is a default id attribute in every model in RoR? You can use this code

> News.find(id).

If you still insist, then an alternative code is:

> News.find_by_club_id(@club_id)

Comment: I chose bad example, I guess.. My bad. I often need to for example list the teams belonging to that club so the code would look something like this: `Team.where("club_id = ?", @club_id).all` which isn't quite sophisticated way to do every time I need to select all things belonging to that club

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write some before filters in your controller. Using your `Team` example:

```
class TeamController < AC
  before_filter :get_club, :only => [ :index ]    # you can limit the filter to methods

  def index
    # because of the before filter you can access club here
    @teams = @club.teams
  end

  # ...

  private
  def get_club
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  end
end
```

This behavior could be moved into a module as well. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more information on filters.

Comment: That is a good solution and it is even more handful when I add the filter into AC so it's available for all controllers. I still wonder if it were possible to manage it through some model-level functionality like deriving all the models from some baseclass and then in baseclass to filter all things belonging to other clubs, any thoughts? I think that would also be quite good for security because then other clubs data couldn't be accessed from other clubs admin functionality

Comment: To move this logic into the model it would actually break up the MVC pattern, since the controller is there to bridge between your view and your model. As for security, with the technique above you can use something like CanCan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to restrict other club admins from seeing data not belonging to them. This is definitely the cleaner solution. If you move this into your models you would still have to communicate with them through the controller which leads to something like `find_by_club_id` again, I'm afraid...